# Check when tkinter window closes

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
if not 'normal' == root.state():
    print('just closed')

root.mainloop()
```

I wanted to check if this tkinter window closes, `print('just closed')` gets executed. I have also tried doing this with a while loop but that does not work since it does not reach the `root.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another way to detect when the window is closed, which is to bind a function to the `<Destroy>` event. However, for the `Tk` widget (unlike for `Frame` or `Button` for instance), `.bind()` also binds to all the widget's children, therefore simply using

```
root.bind("<Destroy>", lambda event: print('just closed'))
```

will not produce the desired result. Indeed, 'just closed' will be printed for the destruction of each widget in the window. To avoid this, we can check that the widget triggering the event is indeed the main window:

```
def on_destroy(event):
    if event.widget != root:
        return
    print("just closed")
```

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="Some text").pack(padx=10, pady=10)
tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

def on_destroy(event):
    if event.widget != root:
        return
    print("just closed")

root.bind("<Destroy>", on_destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Only place the print statement after the `mainloop()`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

root.mainloop()
print('just closed')
```

Comment: Note that with the second solution, the window no longer closes, clicking on the close button only prints "just closed". You need to add `root.destroy()` in the function passed in argument to the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol.

Comment: Also note that `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` callback is not executed when `root.destroy()` is called directly, for example, via a button.

Comment: @j_4321 Yes that's my mistake. I can't find out how it should work to add ```root.destroy()``` in the argument that it works properly. ```root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda arg=root.destroy(): print('just closed'))``` what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @thomkell You can't use a `lambda` there, write a usual function and it will work